# Slider becomes laggy once there are divisions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

This is how a Slider's animation normally looks like:

[image: Normal Behaviour]

This is how a Slider looks when I try to add the *value label*:

[image: Laggy Behaviour]

This is the sample code:

```
          Slider(
              value: sliderValue,
              activeColor: color,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 100.0,
              divisions: 2000,    //TO COMMENT
              label: sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(2),    //TO COMMENT
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sliderValue = value;
                });
              }),
```

In this code, if I comment out the marked `//TO COMMENT` lines which are the `divisions` and `label` properties, the `label goes away as expected, and the animation is *smooth* again.

I assume this is due to `divisions`, and any amount of it, even just `100` does not change the *lag* in any way.

> Additionally, it seems that the `label` property does not work on its own.
> It needs the `divisions` property to also be set so that the ***value
> label*** can be displayed.

What is the workaround so that I can achieve a Slider with the *smoothness shown in the first image*, but *have the default value label* or what looks the same?

Comment: I think it just getting from Slider source-code `_positionAnimationDuration` and `_minimumInteractionTime`. You can take a look on it.

Comment: run ``flutter run --release`` and test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look on source code, you can find [`_positionAnimationDuration`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1223e87f7b1e40ccab3ebc3a212fb24551544f98/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider.dart#L956) which is responsible to animate the slider

[image]

Change it to

```dart
static const Duration _positionAnimationDuration = Duration.zero;
```

Changing on source-code will affect on others project, instead create a local dart file, paste the full slider code and make changes.

Let say we have created `customSlider.dart` file
. Make sure to replace some(`./xyz.dart`) top imports with  `import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';` or material on our `customSlider.dart`.
Then replace `_positionAnimationDuration`.

To use this, import the file

```dart
import 'customSlider.dart' as my_slider;
...
//use case 
my_slider.Slider(....)
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully! However I had to change the source code file instead of making a custom dart file. When I create the custom dart file, I replaced [_positionAnimationDuration](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1223e87f7b1e40ccab3ebc3a212fb24551544f98/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider.dart#L15) line **15** to **20** with one line as `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`. That fixes all the errors leaving just one error, which is [codeScreenshot](https://i.imgur.com/f6AeZ0H.png). Please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
// create class 

 // .yaml > another_xlider: ^1.0.0 

import 'package:another_xlider/another_xlider.dart';
import '../res/res_controller.dart';
import '../utils/utils_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RangeBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<double>? values;
  final double? min;
  final double? max;
  final Function(int, dynamic, dynamic)? onDragging;

  const RangeBar(
      {Key? key,
      @required this.values,
      @required this.onDragging,
      @required this.min,
      @required this.max})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterSlider(
        values: values!,
        // pre set values
        rangeSlider: true,
        handlerAnimation: FlutterSliderHandlerAnimation(
            curve: Curves.elasticOut,
            reverseCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            scale: 1.5),
        jump: true,
        min: min ?? 0,
        max: max ?? 0,
        touchSize: Sizes.s13,
        trackBar: FlutterSliderTrackBar(
          activeTrackBar: BoxDecoration(color: AppColors.orange),
        ),
        tooltip: FlutterSliderTooltip(
          boxStyle: FlutterSliderTooltipBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(Sizes.s5)),
              border: Border.all(
                color: AppColors.steelGray,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          positionOffset: FlutterSliderTooltipPositionOffset(top: -Sizes.s15),
          alwaysShowTooltip: true,
          textStyle:
              TextStyles.defaultRegular.copyWith(fontSize: FontSizes.s11),
       
        ),
        onDragging: onDragging);
  }
}

// try to call 

  Container(
  child: _size(),
   )


 Widget _size() {
    {
      double sizeMin;
      double sizeMax;

        sizeMin =  0;
        sizeMax =  0;

        sizeMax = sizeMin.round() == sizeMax.round() ? sizeMax + 1 : sizeMax;

        return RangeBar(
          values: [
          // add values
          ],
          min: sizeMin,
          max: sizeMax.ceilToDouble(),
          onDragging: (p0, lowerValue, upperValue) {
            
            log(lowerValue);
            log(upperValue);
           
          },
        );
      
      return C0();
    }
  }
```

Comment: That wasn't the issue, I tried the release APK build I made and the issue is the same on my phone with the installed APK.